# About a colored table

Tags: tables, pdftex, colorbox

I am facing a problem of making a table with colored row. The target picture is as follows:

[image]

My own tex code about the required  colored table is as follows:

```
\documentclass[french]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}   
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcommand{\zx}[1]{\textcolor{BlueViolet}{\emph{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|l@{\textcolor{BlueViolet}{$\bullet$}\hspace{7pt}}p{11cm}|}

        \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ \hspace{3mm}\fcolorbox{black}{BlueViolet} { \strut{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Key Points}}} } } \\ \hline 

    &  The verb is a word that expresses either an action (\zx{travailler, marcher}) or a state (\zx{être, paraître}).\\

    &  The verb is the core of the sentence, around which the other elements of the sentence (the subject, object, etc.) are arranged.\\

    &  All clauses must contain a verb.\\

    &  The past participle form of the verb (\zx{parlé, vendu,} etc.) can function as an adjective.\\

    &  The infinitive form (\zx{parler, vendre}) can function as a noun.\\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

  \end{document}
```

The following is my pdf snapshot after compiling my own tex code:

[image]

My question is: How to stretch the colored area to the left boundary of the table. In addition, there exists a tiny gap between the frame of color box and the top line of table. I don not know how to fill this gap such that the table has a perfect appearance as displayed in the target picture. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! please, extend your code snipped to complete small document starting with `\begin{document}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry for the ragged post. That is my first asking problem in this site, and I am not familiar with controlling the typing the code.

Comment: your table has errors! please, make it compilable! and complete code sniped, that we can copy your code and test it.

Comment: @Zarko I post up the complete tex code of my own table in the following, and thank you for your wonderful edited work.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Thank you for your adding the complete tex code to my original post. That makes the post more readable.

Answer (score 6):

May be better a  custom `tcolorbox` than a `tabular` environment? Note that you can change the exact place of "Key Points" with the `yshift` and `xshift` options.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\zx}[1]{\textcolor{blue!85!red}{\emph{#1}}}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{boxsep=1em,left=-1em,
colback=blue!5!white, colframe=blue!75!black, 
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
colbacktitle=blue!85!red!60,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-3mm,xshift=3mm},
title=#2,#1}
\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{Key Points}
 \def\labelitemi{\textcolor{blue!85!red!60}{$\bullet$}}
\begin{itemize}
\item The verb is a word that expresses either an action
      (\zx{travailler, marcher}) or a state 
      (\zx{être, paraître}).
\item The verb is the core of the sentence, around which
      the other elements of the sentence (the subject, 
      object, etc.) are arranged.
\item All clauses must contain a verb.
\item The past participle form of the verb 
      (\zx{parlé, vendu,} etc.) can function as an adjective.
\item The infinitive form (\zx{parler, vendre}) 
      can function as a noun.
\end{itemize}
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I suggest to use `enumitem` packages and with it make itemize list in your table. Also all complication with colored box is better to replace with simple table cell colored by `\cellcolor{<color}{<cell content>}`:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\zx}[1]{\textcolor{BlueViolet}{\emph{#1}}}

\usepackage{enumitem}% <-- added
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}% had to be last in preamble!

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
    \hline
\cellcolor{BlueViolet}{\textcolor{white}{\quad\textbf{Key Points}\quad}}  &   \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{11cm}|}{
    \begin{itemize}[label =\textcolor{BlueViolet}{\textbullet},
                    topsep = 0pt,
                    partopsep = 0pt,
                    leftmargin = *,
                    before = \vspace{-1ex},
                    after = \vspace{-1ex}
                      ]
\item   The verb is a word that expresses either an action (\zx{travailler, marcher}) or a state (\zx{être, paraître}).
\item   The verb is the core of the sentence, around which the other elements of the sentence (the subject, object, etc.) are arranged.
\item   All clauses must contain a verb.
\item   The past participle form of the verb (\zx{parlé, vendu,} etc.) can function as an adjective.
\item   The infinitive form (\zx{parler, vendre}) can function as a noun.
    \end{itemize}
                        }\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Zarko Thank you! Your code dose work! I found that the two letters `Key Points` are not situated in the center of that colored area. It's better to stretch a little toward right side such that the two letters are in center of the colors area. please forgive my nitpicking comments.

Comment: @GL_n, this is not mentioned in your question not has any indication in provided code :-(, bit this is not big problem: just add `\quad` after `Key Points` ... I add this to answer

Comment: @ Zarko Thanks for your modification. Your code is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution which places a framebox only around the itemized items; that way, I believe, the "Key Points" header rectangle is actually given more, rather than less, visual prominence.

[image]

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\zx}[1]{\textcolor{BlueViolet}{\emph{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|l@{\textcolor{BlueViolet}{$\bullet$}\hspace{7pt}}p{11cm}|}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\fcolorbox{black}{BlueViolet}{%
   \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Key Points}}}  } \\
\hline
&  The verb is a word that expresses either an action (\zx{travailler, marcher}) or a state (\zx{être, paraître}).\\

&  The verb is the core of the sentence, around which the other elements of the sentence (the subject, object, etc.) are arranged.\\

&  All clauses must contain a verb.\\

&  The past participle form of the verb (\zx{parlé, vendu,} etc.) can function as an adjective.\\

&  The infinitive form (\zx{parler, vendre}) can function as a noun.\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```